# Django template rendering

Tags: django-templates

when i am rendering my template am getting the below error please help me any one. Thanks in advance.
Note: I added sekizai.context_processors.sekizai in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS  in settings file.

```
You must enable the 'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai' template context processor or use 'sekizai.context.SekizaiContext' to render your templates.
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you using your own view to render the template?
If yes, and the context processor is already added to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, check if you are using RequestContext to render your template:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext


def home(request):
    vars = {'test': 'test'}
    return render_to_response('home.html', RequestContext(request, vars))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your're using Django 1.8 or later and have defined the new setting `TEMPLATES` ([see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#templates)), sekizai will look for the context processors there and **not** in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Answer (score 0):

for people using django 1.8 or later you need to specify the SekizaiContext if you are writing custom views.

```
from sekizai.context import SekizaiContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def home(request):
    vars = {'test': 'test'}
    return render_to_response('home.html', SekizaiContext(request, vars))
```